# How do I delve the following snippet in my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-api, gmail-api

I have this very basic app that lets a user authenticate with google. Once authenticated I would want that user to be displayed a list of his mails. These are the gmail api code snippets that I should be including in my code but I have no idea how and where they go

here's the git repo of my app:
https://github.com/vrukshanikam/oauth-playlist-2

here's the app website:
https://oauth-playlist-2015.herokuapp.com

here's the reference to the gmail apis I'd want to use
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Comment: Can you post some relevant code instead of a link to your git repo?

Comment: I have the entire code to the website in the repo. They're a lot of files and folders routes, models, handlebars, I don't know exactly how and where exactly do I include gmail apis.